# Jenkins: 'Trigger Builds Remotely' with ?token not working when Matrix Authorization Strategy is used

Tags: authentication, jenkins

I'm having a problem with triggering builds in [Jenkins](http://jenkins-ci.org) with authentication enabled and wondering if anyone has ideas.

I have Global Security configured to use LDAP with "Project-based Matrix Authorization Strategy" enabled. The "Anonymous" user has the "Job > Build" privilege, and no other privileges (in particular, the "Anonymous" user does NOT have "Overall > Read" privilege, since I don't want everyone to be able to view the list of jobs and other general information).

I want an automated script to be able to trigger a build using the "Trigger Builds Remotely" feature, where I specify a `?token=[token]` value in the URL and the standard authentication should be bypassed, as long as the `[token]` value matches the one I set in the job's Configure page. The goal is to *NOT* need to provide a regular username/password in the request but simply provide the token for this specific job.

The documentation seems to indicate this should work:
https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Quick+and+Simple+Security

So specifically, I am expecting this HTTP request to work:

```
curl -i https://jenkinsHost/job/ProjectName/build?token=test
```

But I get:

```
[~]$ curl -i https://jenkinsHost/job/ProjectName/build?token=test
HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
Date: Sat, 27 Apr 2013 23:17:03 GMT
Server: Winstone Servlet Engine v0.9.10
Content-Type: text/html;charset=UTF-8
Content-Length: 629
X-Powered-By: Servlet/2.5 (Winstone/0.9.10)
Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID.e9bc4765=e1f0a30b9f04b3740bae527a7822b2d5; Path=/; HttpOnly
Connection: close

<html><head><meta http-equiv='refresh' content='1;url=/login?from=%2Fjob%2FProjectName%2Fbuild%3Ftoken%3Dtest'/>
<script>
window.location.replace('/login?from=%2Fjob%2FProjectName%2Fbuild%3Ftoken%3Dtest');</script>
</head>
<body style='background-color:white; color:white;'>
Authentication required
</body></html>
```

When I *DO* use API authentication, the request works:

```
curl --username "test_user:API_KEY" https://hostname/job/ProjectName/build?token=test
```

But again, according to the documentation I think it is supposed to bypass the global authentication if ?token is present and matches the project token I configure. Why is this not working? What other information/logs can I provide?

Comment: [Related bug report](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-17764). And [what's probably the original report, from 5 years ago](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-1555). Kohsuke writes in one of the comments that build token support is deprecated.

Comment: Yeah I filed [the first one](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-17764) :). But thanks for the second link, perhaps it is intentional but I still think there's a good case in favor of fixing it

Answer (score 40, accepted):

There's a new plugin that allows you to do that even when Jenkins prohibits anonymous read access:

[Build Token Root Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Build+Token+Root+Plugin)

Use:

```
$ curl 'http://jenkins/buildByToken/build?job=jobname&token=mytoken'
Scheduled.
```

Likewise with `buildWithParameters`.

Comment: Thanks! And I noticed it is also possible to pass `&cause=<reason>` in the URL to provide a reason for why the build was triggered, which is handy for tracking purposes

Comment: I installed this plugin and jenkins is still redirecting the curl request to login. Is there any configuration required?

Comment: I'm not seeing the "Trigger Builds Remotely" option on my job after installing the plugin :(

Comment: @exabrial You don't need that option if you have no security enabled on your Jenkins.

Comment: the plugin is now named "Build Authorization Token Root" in the plugin list (https://plugins.jenkins.io/build-token-root)

Answer (score 0):

Example for using the "Build Authorization Token Root" plugin with POST:

```
wget --post-data="job=MyJob&token=SECRET&MyParameter=hello" http://servername/jenkins/buildByToken/buildWithParameters
```

note that "Trigger Builds Remotely" must be activated for this job (with authorization token "SECRET")